# Linode vm with Ubuntu 9.04 can't find vim-full package

Tags: ubuntu, apt, linode

I have fresh linode with ubuntu 9.04. When I try to install the full vim with this command

```
sudo apt-get install vim-full
```

i get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
E: Couldn't find package vim-full
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open /etc/apt/sources.list, are the lines containing "jaunty universe" commented out?  If they are, take out the comment and then do `sudo apt-get update`, and then try to install it again.  If they're not commented out, I'd try `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install vim-full` anyway.

Make sure you open sources.list using sudo, in case you need to edit out those comments.

Comment: Thanks man. That was it. Any idea why these come commented out?

Comment: I just asked some linode people about it, and they said that's how a default Jaunty install comes, and that they didn't do that.  I checked one of my recent Jaunty installs (in VirtualBox, not on linode) and the lines weren't commented out, and I don't recall ever taking out the comments, so I am confused as well.